# Show Glyphicon behind Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have a login form on my page that has 2 bootstrap glyphicons in the user and pass fields. The problem is that they show above my sticky navbar when they scroll passed.

I've tried setting the z-index to a lesser value than the navbar (ie navbar=1 icons=0) but that didn't work.

Why is this happening and how can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a fiddle? z-index shoud work, although apply `position: relative` to the containing `<div>` for the login form.

Comment: Using the z-index is the right way do it. There's just something wrong with your implementation. Please use http://jsfiddle.net/ to help us understand how you implemented it.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate the problem with a fiddle :S http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/7401/

Comment: @MackieeE Sorry I haven't got time just now to set up a fiddle as it is a joomla based website and a little bit of a complicated setup but I'll post back when I can replicate the problem. One thing that is confusing however is that the parent div is hidden by the navbar...

Comment: No worries, but do edit your answer to include which version of Bootstrap too! :)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with Glyphicons passing over a Bootstrap navbar when scrolling by altering the position property in CSS.

```
.glyphicon {
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread... I ran into this problem myself and thought I would share my solution.

I am using font awesome so I add a class of fa when I need to use a glyphicon. The class fa looks like this.

```
.fa{display:inline-block;
font:normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size:inherit;text-rendering:auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
transform:translate(0, 0);}
```

I just removed transform:translate(0, 0) from the class and it works perfectly. Font awesome and bootstrap are very similar when it comes to glyphicons so it should work in both cases... Hope this helps somebody.